# Null in Flex ComboBox

Tags: apache-flex, combobox, null

How can you make a ComboBox where the user can select `null`?

If you simply create a combobox with `null` in the dataprovider, the value appears but the user cannot select it:

```
<mx:ComboBox id="cb" dataProvider="{[null, 'foo', 'bar']}" />
```

Is there a way to make that null selectable?

A workaround is to add an item into the dataProvider that is not null but 'represents' null; and then map between null and that object every time you access the combobox. But that's not really an elegant solution; you would always have to keep this mapping in mind in all code that accesses a 'nullable' combobox...

Edit: expanding on why I don't like the workaround:
It could be done in a subclass of course, but either I introduce new attributes (like `nullableSelectedItem`); but then you have to be careful to always use these attributes. Or I override ComboBoxes `selectedItem`; but I'm affraid that is going to break the base class: it might not like something changing its idea of what the current selected item is from within. And even this fragile hack works, on top of `selectedItem` and `dataProvider` this nullItem then also needs to be handled special in `data` and `listData` for renderers, in `labelFunction`, and then it's probably still being exposed in events the ComboBox sends...
It might work, but it's quite a hack just to fix the problem that if the user clicks on the item it isn't activated (for the rest the ComboBox handles null fine).
(Another alternative is to have a ui component delegate to a ComboBox, but that's even much more code just to avoid this small problem)

Comment: You could make a subclass of ComboBox which encapsulates just this nulling behavior.

Comment: Any thoughts on Spark ComboBox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution is likely the simpliest one:

```
<mx:ComboBox id="cb" dataProvider="{[{label:"", data:null}, {label:'foo', data:'foo'}, {label:'bar', data:'bar'}]}" />
```

and access the data using `cb.selectedItem.data`

However, this simple solution is not binding-friendly, as Wouter mentioned.

So here is **a more tricky solution that will allow selecting null objects**:

```
<mx:ComboBox id="cb" dataProvider="{[null, 'foo', 'bar']}" dropdownFactory="{new ClassFactory(NullList)}" />
```

Where NullList is the following class:

```
package test
{
import mx.controls.List;

public class NullList extends List
{
    public function NullList()
    {
        super();
    }

    override public function isItemSelectable(data:Object):Boolean
    {
        if (!selectable)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: That is a simplified version of the workaround. But this doesn't event allow you to bind the selectedItem to a model. In other words, you can't do something like <mx:Combobox ... selectedItem="{model.currentProduct}" /> with this.

Comment: Yes, you're right, binding will be harder for that solution. (but it's still possible - you can bind to selectedIndex and use a simple function to get item index).

I've come up with the solution which solves your exact problem. Hope that helps

Comment: Nice! Exactly what I was looking for.
It does have one cosmetic issue: the null item does not light up when hovering the mouse over it.

Comment: Yep, I'll try to find some time to fix it in a couple of days. It's even more complicated, cause it happens somewhere deep inside List (or even ListBase) component.
Feel free to post your own answer if you figure how to fix it yourself.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the only way to correctly manage an empty item is to actually add an item to the dataprovider of the combobox. The following subclass will handle this automatically.

The implementation is a little tricky in order to support changes on dataprovider, in terms of items add/remove and of complete reassignment of the dataprovider itself (just think about arraycollections bindings to remote services' response).

`package {`

```
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.FocusEvent;
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    import mx.collections.ICollectionView;
    import mx.collections.IList;
    import mx.containers.FormItem;
    import mx.controls.ComboBox;
    import mx.events.CollectionEvent;
    import mx.events.ListEvent;
    import mx.validators.Validator;

    public class EmptyItemComboBox extends ComboBox {

        protected var _emptyItem:Object = null;
        protected var _originalDataProvider:ICollectionView = null;

        public function EmptyItemComboBox() {
            super();
            addEmptyItem();
            addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onChange);
        }

        private function onChange(event:Event):void {
            dispatchEvent(new Event("isEmptySelectedChanged"));
        }

        [Bindable]
        public function get emptyItem():Object {
            return _emptyItem;
        }

        public function set emptyItem(value:Object):void {
            if (_emptyItem != value) {
                clearEmptyItem();
                _emptyItem = value;
                addEmptyItem();
            }
        }

        [Bindable(event="isEmptySelectedChanged")]
        public function get isEmptySelected():Boolean {
                return (selectedItem == null || (_emptyItem != null && selectedItem == _emptyItem));
        }

        override public function set selectedItem(value:Object):void {
            if (value == null && emptyItem != null) {
                super.selectedItem = emptyItem;
            } else    if (value != selectedItem) {
                super.selectedItem = value;
            }
            dispatchEvent(new Event("isEmptySelectedChanged"));
        }

        override public function set dataProvider(value:Object):void {
            if (_originalDataProvider != null) {
                _originalDataProvider.removeEventListener(
                        CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE,
                        onOriginalCollectionChange);
            }
            super.dataProvider = value;
            _originalDataProvider = (dataProvider as ICollectionView);
            _originalDataProvider.addEventListener(
                    CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE,
                    onOriginalCollectionChange)
            addEmptyItem();
        }

        private function clearEmptyItem():void {
            if (emptyItem != null && dataProvider != null 
                    && dataProvider is IList) {
                var dp:IList = dataProvider as IList;
                var idx:int = dp.getItemIndex(_emptyItem);
                if (idx >=0) {
                    dp.removeItemAt(idx);    
                }
            }
            dispatchEvent(new Event("isEmptySelectedChanged"));
        }

        private function addEmptyItem():void {
            if (emptyItem != null) {
                 if (dataProvider != null && dataProvider is IList) {
                    var dp:IList = dataProvider as IList;
                    var idx:int = dp.getItemIndex(_emptyItem);
                    if (idx == -1) {
                        var newDp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(dp.toArray().concat());
                        newDp.addItemAt(_emptyItem, 0);
                        super.dataProvider = newDp;
                    }
                }
            }
            dispatchEvent(new Event("isEmptySelectedChanged"));
        }

        private function onOriginalCollectionChange(event:CollectionEvent):void {
            if (_emptyItem != null) {
                dataProvider = _originalDataProvider;
                addEmptyItem();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some notes about the class:

- It will insert the empty object automatically on the list.. this was a strong requirements for my scenario: the dataproviders was returned by remote services and they couldn't include additional elements just to support the Flex UI, neither I could manually watch every collection to create empty items on each collection refresh.
- Since it has to work with the contents of the collection, it will internally create a copy of the original one with the same items' instances AND the empty one, so the instance of the original collection will not be touched at all and can be reused in other context.
- It will listen for changes on the original dataprovider, allowing to work on it and even to assign a competely new one: the empty item will be recreated automatically.
- You are in control providing the actual instance to use as the "empty item" with the emptyItem attribute: this allows to keep a consistent data type with the rest of the collection (if you use typed objects), or to define a custom label on it.

Some example code using it...

```
    <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
    ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:ArrayCollection id="myDP">
    <mx:source>
        <mx:Array>
            <mx:Object value="1" label="First"/>  
            <mx:Object value="2" label="Second"/>
            <mx:Object value="3" label="Third"/>
        </mx:Array>
    </mx:source>
    </mx:ArrayCollection>

    <local:EmptyItemComboBox id="comboBox" dataProvider="{myDP}" labelField="label">
    <local:emptyItem>
        <mx:Object value="{null}" label="(select an item)"/>  
    </local:emptyItem>
    </local:EmptyItemComboBox>

    <mx:Button label="Show selected item" click="Alert.show(comboBox.selectedItem.value)"/>

    <mx:Button label="Clear DP" click="myDP.removeAll()"/>
    <mx:Button label="Add item to DP" click="myDP.addItem({value: '4', label: 'Fourth'})"/>
    <mx:Button label="Reset DP" click="myDP = new ArrayCollection([{value: '1', label: 'First'}])"/>

    <mx:Label text="{'comboBox.isEmptySelected = ' + comboBox.isEmptySelected}"/>

</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Your code for automatically adding it, and watching the original collection for changes looks good.
But as I explained in the question, I really don't like having an emptyItem 'representing' null; and with the NullList proposed by Hrundik that is not needed anymore.

Comment: If you control the creation of your dataprovider collections (and thus you have the chance to add the null one), the solution suggested by Hrundik is the way to go (big fan of the KISS principle here :)

My subclass is not about having a real object instance vs a null reference (it could be rewritten use the null item / dropDownFactory method).

It is more focused of managing this things when your collection could be refreshed at any time and you're not in control of this, which is a pretty common scenario. I Hope it could be useful if someone is dealing with the same issue.

Comment: I Like your solution. Thanks. My previous idea was close to this, but the implementation had problems. Now I just simplified a little bit your one: instead of emptyItem, I use emptyLabel (string).

Comment: I've just refactored the approach, wrapping any source IList in a custom FixedElementsList (implementing IList) that will keep a set of fixed elements added on top of the original source, see the source on my github https://github.com/cosma/Apache-Flex-Personal-Whiteboard/blob/master/FixedElementsList.as

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is impossible. 
How ever, a good solution that will not make you "have to keep this mapping in mind" is to create a class inherits from ComboBox with its own DataProvider property.

this property setter will handle the null values and have a representation for it on the super ComboBox class.

Comment: I don't really like it. But as long as nobody comes up with something that makes a "real" null selectable, I guess you're right: it is impossible, and the best we can do is encapsulate the workaround as much as possible in a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

A really simple, but also very limited solution is to add a prompt="" attribute..

This will prevent the ComboBox from selecting the first item in the dataProvider automatically, but as soon as the user select an item, the empty row will not be displayed anymore.

Comment: Being able to still select the empty row is quite essential, it what the whole question is about.

Comment: Supporting this scenario requires some complex coding.. Please take a look at my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

requireSelection="false" will allow a blank value and prompt allows you to enter the text use for that blank value if you'd like.